# Simplify same css for multiple different classes?

Tags: css

I'm a newbie, and I spent a lot to find answer but I think I didn't search correctly.

How do I write this in one line?

```
.black h1 {
   color: #ffffff !important;
}
.black h2 {
   color: #ffffff !important;
}
.black h3 {
   color: #ffffff !important;
}
.black p {
   color: #ffffff !important;
}
```

Thanks In advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want specify only these elements

> .black h1, .black h2, .black h3, .black p { color: #fff; !important; }

But if you want all elements inside this class

> .black * {  color: #fff !important; }

Answer (score 2):

```
.black h1, .black h2, .black h3, .black p {
   color: #fff !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By a coma:

```
.black h1, .black h2, .black h3, .black p {
   color: #ffffff !important;
}
```

Comment: Hey newbie! Don't forget to accept the answer it can help other newbies :)

Comment: As you can see [here](https://jsfiddle.net/vLgznwzu/1/), your code doesn't work as it selects all `h2`, `h3` and `p` and not all `h2`, `h3` and `p` **inside** a `.black`

Comment: Of course you're right I didn't bay attention, I forgot to copy past the `black` class.
Newbie! don't forget it also :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I really appreciate your help! :)